# How to export TextField to text file as same format?

Tags: java, textfield

```
String Hasil = TextHasil.getText();
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/steve/Desktop/HasilDekripsi.txt")) {
            out.println(Hasil);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {        
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cunjO.png): [image]

Comment: Side note, please use the standard conventions for variable names; Namely that variables should start with a lowercase letter: `Hasil` -> `hasil`. It makes it easier for us to read and also, as you see, the syntax highlighter has trouble when it is not in this standard format, it's highlighting `Hasil` is if it were a type.

Comment: thanks for the advice will be edit soon

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing newline character:

```
out.println(Hasil.replaceAll("\n","\n\n"));
```

OR

```
out.println(Hasil.replaceAll("\n","\r\n"));
```

You can get line separator independent of platform:

`System.getProperty("line.separator")` OR
`System.lineSeparator();`

Comment: still same like the picture, i will search again